# Para que serve export FLASK_APP e FLASK_ENV?

Tags: python, flask

Eu estou aprendendo flask agora e entendi que, toda vez que vou rodar minha aplicação, preciso rodar antes:

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

Eu apenas decorei que preciso fazer isso, mas não entendi o porquê. Para onde estou exportando esses comandos? Qual a função deles? Realmente preciso fazer isso toda vez (mesmo em um projeto que já fiz isso antes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

São variáveis de ambiente que ajudam o Flask a entender como se comportar.

A primeira,`FLASK_APP` pode ser deixada vazia e então ele procurará por "app" ou "wsgi" (com ou sem o ".py" no final, ou seja, pode ser um arquivo ou um módulo) mas você pode ausar:

- Um arquivo/módulo no diretório atual, por exemplo `FLASK_APP=src/hello`;
- Um módulo a ser importado, como `FLASK_APP=hello.web`;
- Uma instância específica dentro do módulo, algo como `FLASK_APP=hello:app2` ou
- Executar diretamente a *factory* `create_app()` e até com passagem de parâmetros, tipo `FLASK_APP=hello:create_app('dev')"`.

Estes exemplos eu pequei da [documentação do Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/).

Já a `FLASK_ENV`define o tipo de ambiente de execução do projeto, os valores reconhecidos são dois, "production" e "development", se nada for definido ele usará "production" por padrão.

E sua função é ligar/desligar determinados comportamentos dentro do Flask e extensões, por exemplo, usar "development" ligará o modo de depuração ("DEBUG").